# Can you set a controller for multiple models in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

So I'm trying to add comments to 3 different models (Comments for movies, directors, and actors all foreign keyed to their id) but it feels like it would be very inefficient to create a model, controller, service, and repository for each one of them and that it would be easiest to just create a new comment model for each and put them all into a single controller and work on it from there. Is that possible? Or is there an even more efficient way to do this through a single model? It doesn't seem like it is possible as they are set up as a many-to-one relationship. I just want to be sure that it isn't bad practice or anything like that to do, I'd just rather not have so much extra code that feels repeated. Can anyone give some advice on this? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I think this would be a good idea to use the same `Comment` entity/table for all of your models (movies, directors and actors) if the comment structure is going to be the same. However, if comments are likely to be different (movies comments != director comments, with many different properties) then maybe you should go for distinct entities/tables. It's actually up to you, there are no "good" or "bad" practices at this point I'd say, just discussable choices.

Comment: The comments will be the exact same, the only difference between them would be that movie comments are many-to-one with movie id, director comments to director id, etc. I don't know how to set up a model that would do something like that and be able to be set many-to-one to multiple entities based on different ids. Hopefully that made sense

Comment: As the comment structure is the same you can create a comment entity and resolve the many-to-many mapping using the tables with the keys (movieId, commentId), (directorId, commentId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps combining the POSTing of comments into a single endpoint may be achieved as such:

```
@PostMapping("/{targetType}/{targetTypeId}/comments")
```

Where targetType may be either 'movies', 'directors' or 'actors' and targetTypeId refers to the exact instance the comment should be linked to.

In the comment DB table, there will need to be a column TYPE_ID indicating which of the three target types the comment refers to and a column TYPE_INSTANCE_ID pointing to either a movie, director or actor.

```
| COMMENT table columns |
| ID | TYPE_ID | TYPE_INSTANCE_ID | COMMENT |
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you for the example! I will give it a go and see how it works, it seems like it should do what I'm looking for.